# jQuery .animate, confusion between delay and duration

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, animation, coffeescript, jquery-animate

I'm trying to make a personal website and I have a situation with jQuery.
The `.animate` function behaves oddly.

I have this *CofeeScript* code which is supposed to animate the orange links on the right of the experiences sections [here](http://jlpouffier.me/experiences)

```
$(".resume_show, .experiences_index, .experiences_show").ready ->
# The above scoping is possible with the awesome pluging  jquery-readyselector

  $("div.link_txt").rotate -90
  $("section.preview").hover (->
    $(this).children("a").stop(true).animate width: "40px", 0, "swing"
    $(this).children("a").children("img").stop(true).fadeIn 500
    $(this).children("a").children("div.link_txt").stop(true).fadeIn 500
    return
  ), ->
    $(this).children("a").stop(true).animate width: "5px", 0, "swing"
    $(this).children("a").children("img").stop(true).fadeOut 100
    $(this).children("a").children("div.link_txt").stop(true).fadeOut 100
    return
  return
```

As you can notice, I had to fix the `duration` at `0`, because jQuery took this for a delay.

I tried to copy/paste my code on JSFiddle to ask you why I encounter this strange behaviour, but it is working perfectly : http://jsfiddle.net/8s3Fn/

**So I think it is an issue with my dev environment :**

I develop on Ruby On Rails. Maybe one of the other gems is not compatible, however since jQuery is included by default I doubt it.

This is my Gemfile :

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.1.0'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.2'

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

# Rail administration
gem 'devise'
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'gregbell/active_admin'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sprockets'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

# Markdown support
gem 'redcarpet'

# Sucurity token issue
gem "figaro"

# Bread Crum
gem "crummy", "~> 1.8.0"

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.1.2'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

To conclude, when I open the Firefox console and hover the sections, I have these messages :

```
reflow: 0.18ms
reflow: 0.16ms
reflow: 0.31ms
reflow: 0.16ms
reflow: 0.32ms
reflow: 0.18ms
reflow: 0.18ms
reflow: 0.2ms
```

I have other moving parts animated with `.animate` of jQuery, and everything works :

- The duration is, indeed, the duration
- No messages on the console

For the other moving parts, `.animate` operates on `left` or `top`

For the odd ones, `.animate` operates on `width`

Do you have any idea why I have this issue ?

Comment: what are you trying to do? it's working for me

Comment: Yes I know it's working ... It's not supposed to since I put duration to zero (it supposed to pop from nowhere). I'm trying to make jQuery works as it has to be. I also want to change the duration of this animation but I cant'...

Comment: what jquery version are you using?

Comment: I'm using jQuery 1.11.1

Comment: ok there are couple of things that i want to point out first you all you need not pass `swing` option as it's default and secondly you need not nest your selectors like `.children().children` that just make it look ugly and btw i just tested your code by changing delay to `1000` and it works for me on your site

Comment: posting js i used in developer console on your site

Answer (score 0):

As i pointed out in my comment. *You need not use use swing option as it's default by* [`docs`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

You also need not nest your selectors with `.children("selector1").childern("selector2")` that just makes your code look big and ugly instead you could simply do `.children("selector1 selector2")`.

Used this code in the developer console on your website and it works, *this code is in javascript though as browsers don't understand coffeescript*

```
$(".resume_show, .experiences_index, .experiences_show").ready(function() {
  $("div.link_txt").rotate(-90);
  $("section.preview").hover((function() {
    $(this).children("a").stop(true).animate({width: "40px"}, 1000);
    $(this).children("a img").stop(true).fadeIn(500);
    $(this).children("a div.link_txt").stop(true).fadeIn(500);
  }), function() {
    $(this).children("a").stop(true).animate({width: "5px"}, 1000);
    $(this).children("a").children("img").stop(true).fadeOut(100);
    $(this).children("a div.link_txt").stop(true).fadeOut(100);
  });
});
```

Also since you are using  turbolinks i will recommend rather than using `ready` you should use [**`on event`**](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: That is really weird : I copy/pasted your code my my text editor, I even changed the extension to be in JavaScript and : 

1) The animation is delayed of about 1 second.
2) the `.children("a b")` selector do not work.

I really have an issue with my jQuery, but thank you anyway.

Comment: @Jenova70 can you try it in your developer console on your site and see if it works? cuz it worked for me

Comment: No, I thought it was a local problem so I deployed my app (on heroku) with `1000` in duration to see if it was working in production. But no, I had to get back to my inexplicable `0`

Comment: @Jenova70 this is strange. Did you get any errors in console when you tried my code because you said it didn't work in your first comment

Comment: Yes i tried to copy/pasted your code on my EDITOR and it didn't worked ... It's not important, the result is still good... But i wish I could use jQuery the right way and (for example) be able to change the duration

Comment: @Jenova70 i'm curious though why it didn't work for you.

Comment: Me too ! You can extract my minified js file for my web site and search for _".experiences_index"_ for example ... You'll find the code actually deployed and the syntax is good and there is a ZERO for the duration. The thing amazing is that the function just before is supposed to animate my navigation panel. It is __exactly__ the same syntax but duration is working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56904/discussion-between-mandeep-and-jenova70).